# Is there a way to hide the column names on SQL inserts in the terminal (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I have over 100 columns for a model, and when I'm creating new records, I see over 100 columns in the terminal being outputted (which makes the terminal unreadable).

For example, I see something like this:

```
SQL (13.5ms)  INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" 
# dozens and dozens of columns are displayed here
```

Is there a way to hide (or truncate) terminal logs from outputting every column from a model when I'm creating a record?

Comment: You can try to change the log_level to :info. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Comment: Great and simple solution! Just what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try writing the create part of code inside a `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.silence` block ?

Comment: this makes sure you are not editing the log level and dont have to reset it as well :) This block will do it for you ;)